# Doesn't boost::log respect keywords::max_size when custom collector is set?

Tags: c++, logging, boost, boost-log

I am using Boost 1.61 and what I ultimately want is:

1. Rotate current log file if its size is reaching `FILE_ROTATION_SIZE`
2. Handle the rotated file with a custom collector for further compression (is this the right way for compressing rotated files?)
3. Remove some of oldest (desirably compressed) files if the total size of files reaches `FILES_MAX_SIZE`

Now, without any collector I can achieve points 1 and 3 just with the following snippet

```
sink = logging::add_file_log(
      keywords::file_name = fileName,
      keywords::rotation_size = FILE_ROTATION_SIZE,
      keywords::scan_method = sinks::file::scan_method::scan_matching,
      keywords::target = logDir.native(),
      keywords::max_size = FILES_MAX_SIZE,
      keywords::format =
      (
         expr::stream
            << expr::format_date_time< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
            << " " << expr::attr< boost::log::attributes::current_thread_id::value_type >("ThreadID") << " "
            << "<" << expr::attr< Logger::SeverityLevel >("Severity") << "> "
            << expr::message
            << expr::attr< std::wstring >("Suffix")
      ),
      keywords::auto_flush = true

   );
```

However, when setting a collector with `sink->locked_backend()->set_file_collector(_fileCollector);` inherited from

`boost::log::sinks::file::collector` which for now does basically nothing **the files still continue rotate, but older files don't get removed.**

Here is how the collector looks like:

```
class FileCollector : public boost::log::sinks::file::collector
{
   virtual void store_file(boost::filesystem::path const& src_path) override;

   virtual uintmax_t scan_for_files(boost::log::sinks::file::scan_method method,
                                       boost::filesystem::path const& pattern = boost::filesystem::path(),
                                       unsigned int* counter = 0) override;
};

void FileCollector::store_file(boost::filesystem::path const& src_path)
{
   LOG << "src_path: " << src_path;
}

uintmax_t FileCollector::scan_for_files(boost::log::sinks::file::scan_method method,
                                                boost::filesystem::path const& pattern,
                                                unsigned int* counter)
{
   return 1;
}
```

`scan_for_files()` is not being called at all.

From [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45134324/705886), I can see author says `max_size` is a collector parameter, so I assume there should be some kind of way of setting it in my `FileCollector` class. Calling `sinks::file::make_collector()` instead of inheriting custom collector seems is not an option, because it doesn't have means for providing the desired `store_file()` callback, where I plan to put the compression logic.

Does this mean that I should keep tracking the total size and handle the deletion when needed by myself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this the right way for compressing rotated files?

Yes, if you have to do this within your application. Note that unless you're using asynchronous logging, log file rotation is done synchronously. This means that some random log statements in your application will take a rather long time to complete while the log file is being compressed.

A better solution could be using a separate service such as logrotate that will handle log rotation and compression without interfering with your application performance.

> Does this mean that I should keep tracking the total size and handle the deletion when needed by myself?

Yes, the file collector is fully responsible for managing the rotated files. Whenever `store_file` is called, your file collector has to perform the necessary steps to compress and store the file in the target storage and possibly remove any older files.

The parameters like `target` and `max_size` are interpreted by the file collector implemented in Boost.Log, which is created by `sinks::file::make_collector`. If you implement your own collector, you have to initialize it in your own way - possibly by passing these parameters to the collector constructor.

Comment: Thank you very much, Andrey! +1 for detailed answer and alternative suggestion. Do you think it is a bad idea to perform compression in a new thread and return from store_file() immediately?

Comment: Doing compression in a separate thread would solve the blocking problem, but it would complicate implementation. In particular, you would have to address the case if your application needs to terminate while the compression is in progress. Note that `store_file` still has to move the file away before returning, otherwise the sink may overwrite it.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again!